# How do I select quantities for each day, for each item?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a database and its designed roughly like this:

```
tblParts
----------
partID

tblOrders
----------
partID
date
quantity
```

Ultimately I'd like to product output that looks something like this:

```
partID   Aug 10   Aug 11   Aug 12 ... (say .. 100 days)
M061101  5        25       15
M061102  10       0        20
```

I can write a query to grab all the info for a single part:

```
SELECT * FROM tblParts LEFT JOIN tblOrders USING (partID);
```

but the results span many rows. So for many parts ... lots and lots of rows. How can I construct a query to return one row per part?

The ideal situation is being able to chose a range of dates and ending up with one row per part for that range of dates.

Comment: You would be much better off making a pivot table in Excel. Also I don't see why you would bother joining the tblparts table. The partid column is already on the tblorders table. Unless tblparts also has a description field that you want to bring back, there is no point. In either case you could use an inner join, there's no need for an outer join given that I assume orders can only be placed for parts that exist.

Comment: @brian-demilia because in posting a question its easier for those reading to simplify as much as possible. In what real-world database would a table have a single column for inventory number and nothing else?